# Como quitar letras de una palabra?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente palabra "ASTRONAUTA", y quiero mostrarla en un alert, siempre se debe mostrar la primer letra de la palabra seguido de la vocal mas próxima, tendria que quedar asi = "AO", nose si me explico, tendria que servir para cualquier palabra, pongo otra de ejemplo "GEOGRAFÍA" tendria que mostrarse asi = "GE" siempre dejando la primer letra y despues la vocal mas cercana. Que funcion serviria?

Comment: Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, deberias poner algo de codigo que hayas intentado para ver por donde has tirado y podamos ayudarte. Mirate https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tomar la primera letra de la palabra considerando como si ésta fuese un `Array`, despues puedes recorrer la palabra desde la posición `1` y encontrar la primera coincidencia que haya con una vocal, e aquí el ejemplo:

```
function myWord(word) {

    var custom=word[0];

    for (var i=1; i < word.length; i++) {
        var letter = word[i];
        if (/[aeiou]/i.test(letter)) {
             custom+=letter;
             break;
        }
    }

    return custom;
}

myWord('Esternocleidomastoideo'); //Ee
```

También puedes optar por usar `.toUpperCase()` cuando devuelves la variable `custom` para que las **dos letras que te devuelva sean mayúsculas**.